# why not show existing raw in SQLite browser

Tags: android, sqlite

[image]I'm fire this query in SQLIte Manager like

```
  SELECT * FROM All_Post where ActivityId =020150928163171054;
```

but can not show any data of this row from this **All_Post** table, because raw data is present in this **All_Post table**.What is the wrong with .

Comment: nothing wrong, you dont have a row with `ActivityId  == 020150928163600039`

Comment: Yes , I have data roe with ActivityId == 020150928163600039 , but why not show this data .

Comment: you dont have a row with `ActivityId == 020150928163600039`

Comment: I have this row data in table All_Post .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have a row where the value in the `ActitivyId` column is `020150928163171054`.

For some reason, all values in your table are strings. In SQL, a string value must be written as `'020150928163171054'`.

Comment: Thanks you save my day .